# Перезагрузка операторов сравнения

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно было перезагрузить операторы сравнения и я это сделал как знал. Так как типы были разные получилось вот это:

```
///Реляционные операторы
//-----------------Money and Money----------------------------------------    
friend bool operator== (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
friend bool operator!= (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
friend bool operator> (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
friend bool operator< (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
friend bool operator>= (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
friend bool operator<= (const Money& first, const Money& second) noexcept;
//-----------------double and Money---------------------------------------
friend bool operator== (const double first, const Money& second) noexcept;
...
friend bool operator<= (const double first, const Money& second) noexcept;
//------------------Money and double--------------------------------------
friend bool operator== (const Money& first, const double second) noexcept;
...
friend bool operator<= (const Money& first, const double second) noexcept;
```

В итоге получилось 18 операторов. Хотел узнать **можно ли это как-то сократить?**

Класс Money используется другим классом Goods. Поле цены в Goods является Money. В методах Goods идет сравнение цен с типами double, int. Пример:

```
//_cost - типа Money
if (_cost < 0)
        throw string("ERR - " + to_string(_cost.MoneyToDouble()) + " < 0");
    this->cost = _cost;
```

Comment: ¿А зачем там еще сравнения с `double`? ¿Может не надо?

Comment: Мне необходимо это сравнение, т.к. данный класс Money используется в другом классе Goods (Товары), где необходимо сравнивать цену товара Goods с значениями double

Comment: ¿Почему бы не хранить и в том другом классе деньги в виде объекта `Money`? А не просто `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` - [сомнительный тип для хранения денег](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Лучше возьмите целочисленный тип, и храните в целых копейках/центах/...

---

> можно ли это как-то сократить?

Можно! Но нужен [*spaceship operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) из C++20: `<=>`

Если у `Money` есть не-explicit конструктор от `double`, то так:

```
#include <compare>

class Money
{
    double value = 0;
    
  public:
    Money(double value) : value(value) {}

    friend auto operator<=>(const Money &a, const Money &b) = default;
};
```

Это дает вам все операторы сравнения: `==`,`!=`,`<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=` - между `Money`-`Money`, и `Money`-`double`.

Если нужна кастомная логика сравнения полей, а не дефолтная, тогда так:

```
#include <compare>

class Money
{
    double value = 0;
    
  public:
    Money(double value) : value(value) {}

    friend auto operator<=>(const Money &a, const Money &b)
    {
        return a.value <=> b.value;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Money &a, const Money &b)
    {
        return a.value == b.value;
    }
};
```

Заметьте, что если `<=>` не default, то он дает только `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`. Чтобы получить `==` и `!=`, нужно руками написать `==`.

Если у `Money` нет не-explicit конструктора от `double`, то нужен второй `<=>` между `Money` и `double`:

```
#include <compare>

class Money
{
    double value = 0;
    
  public:
    explicit Money(double value) : value(value) {}

    friend auto operator<=>(const Money &a, const Money &b) = default;

    friend auto operator<=>(const Money &a, double b)
    {
        return a.value <=> b;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Money &a, double b)
    {
        return a.value == b;
    }
};
```

Несмотря на кажущуюся несимметричность `==`, он (и `!=`) работают независимо от порядка операндов.

Comment: Вот утащили они с перла <=>, а почему == я все равно должен определить - не понятно...

Comment: @KoVadim Думаю, потому что `==` часто можно написать быстрее, чем через `a <=> b == 0`. Например, для строк можно сначала сравнить длину, а уже потом посимвольно.

Comment: написать быстрее или "будет работать быстрее"? Какую критику делали этим всем операторам сравнения (кстати, как пример, приводилась реализация строки с ее 18 операторами сравнения!!) - я могу легко ошибиться и написать равно так, что оно будет несоответствовать тому, что в a<=>b==0 и потом долго и нужно искать (а бывает нужно ещё доказать, что это так). Попытался найти в документации подтвержение "что если <=> не default, то он дает только <,<=,>,>=", но не вижу

Comment: @KoVadim Будет работать быстрее (опять же, пример - `std::string`). *"подтвержение "что если <=> не default, то"* [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons#Defaulted_three-way_comparison), начиная со слов *"If `operator<=>` is defaulted"*. *"Какую критику делали этим всем операторам"* Эту часть не понял.

Comment: я говорю о этом https://youtu.be/tKtJn34qpww?t=278 (я поставил прям метку на слайд). Да, проверил, при ручном (пользовательском) <=>, оператор == не генерируется... я не понимаю, почему. И на последок, писать тип auto для <=>  это как по мне печально. там strong/weak/partial...

Comment: @KoVadim А что значит "какую критику делали"? Вот что я не понял. *"== не генерируется... я не понимаю, почему"* Ну дык, чтобы побудить написать руками более оптимизированный, чем через `a <=> b == 0`. Как минимум просто попарно сравнить поля через `==`, что уже потенциально быстрее. *"писать тип auto для <=> это как по мне печально"* Зато не надо думать, какой ставить. :)

Comment: что бы побудить ручками? неа, это не то. У нас по факту нарушения правила единой ответственности. Если есть две возможности написать оператор ==, то гарантировано будет ошибка.